# Lightning Component error - DEV - QA

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to upload a lightning component to my QA environment but the error occurs:

> aura/HipoteseDiagnostica/HipoteseDiagnostica.cmp -- Error:
>   c.HipoteseDiagnostica:
>   org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Could not parse a number [1, 1]: ''

When saving this component in the development environment this error does not occur.

This is my component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:layout,forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
  access="global" controller = "EMEDHipoteseDiagnosticaAura">

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

  <!--Atributo de Lista de CID's selecionados no LOOKUPCOMPONENT-->
  <aura:attribute name="listaCID" type="list"/>

  <!--Atributo para exibir o nome do Paciente-->
  <aura:attribute name="nomePaciente" type="String"/>

  <!--Atributo de Lista de elementos do Aura:Iteration-->
  <aura:attribute name="listaAdicionar" type="list" default="[]" />

  <!--Atributo utilizado para adicionar mais uma linha ao "listaAdicionar"-->
  <aura:attribute name="contador" type="Integer" default="0" />

  <!--Atributo utilizado para guardar o valor do LOOKUPCOMPONENT que fica fora do Aura:Iteration-->
  <aura:attribute name="lookupFixo" type="sObject"/>

  <!--Atributo utilizado para guardar o valor do campo observação-->
  <aura:attribute name="observacao" type="String" default=""/>

  <!--Atributo utilizado para exibir mensagem de erro caso o campo principal de CID 
      não seja preenchido antes de salvar-->
  <aura:attribute name="msgValidaLookup" type="String" default="" access="public"/>
  <aura:attribute name="msgValidaLookupFixo" type="String" default=""/>
  <aura:attribute name="msgvalidaSalvar" type="String" default=""/>

  <!--Atributo utilizado para guardar o ID da consulta (tela anterior)-->
  <aura:attribute name="consultaId" type="String" default="" />

  <!--Atributo utilizado para exibir/esconder o Spinner-->
  <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="String" default="" />

  <!--Atributo utilizado para salvar o link da página de Consulta-->
  <!--<aura:attribute name="paginaConsulta" type="String" default="" />-->

  <!--Atributo utilizado para esconder o primeiro botão "Adicionar outro CID"-->
  <aura:attribute name="hideAdicionar" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

  <aura:attribute name="indexValidacao" type="Integer" default="" />


  <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header- -object-home">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="10" class="section-padding-top">
      <lightning:card title="NOVA HIPÓTESE DIAGNÓSTICA">
        <hr />
        <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label">Paciente: <strong>{!v.nomePaciente}</strong></label>
          <div class="slds-section__content"> 
            <div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}" >
                    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="medium"/>
                </aura:if>
                <c:LookupComponent aura:id="lookupChild" objectName="CIDs__c" fieldName="Name" campos="Id, Name"
                  label="CID" labelitalico="(Digite ao menos 3 iniciais do CID ou nome da doença)"
                  messageLookup="Mostrar todos os CIDs com essa descrição"
                  placeholder=""
                  listaGenerica="{!c.getEventoGenerico}" registroRemovido="{!c.getRegistroRemovido}" lookupFixo="true" 
                  method="{!c.parentValida}"/>
                  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.listaAdicionar.length > 0}">
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                      <lightning:button class="btnAddCID" title="Adicionar outro CID" type="button"
                      label="ADICIONAR OUTRO CID" onclick="{!c.addCIDrow}"></lightning:button>
                    </aura:set>
                  </aura:if>

              <p style="color: red">{!v.msgvalidaSalvar}</p>
              <p style="color: red">{!v.msgValidaLookupFixo}</p>

              <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="slds-grid_vertical max-1">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.listaAdicionar}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                  <div class="container">
                    <c:LookupComponent objectName="CIDs__c" fieldName="Name" campos="Id, Name"
                      label="CID" labelitalico="(Digite ao menos 3 iniciais do CID ou nome da doença)"
                      messageLookup="Mostrar todos os CIDs com essa descrição"
                      placeholder=""
                      listaGenerica="{!c.getEventoGenerico}" registroRemovido="{!c.getRegistroRemovido}"
                      index="{!index}"/>
                      <lightning:button class="btnRemoveCID" name="{!index}" title="Remover CID" type="button"
                      label="REMOVER" onclick="{!c.removerCIDrow}"></lightning:button>
                      <aura:if isTrue="{!index == v.listaAdicionar.length - 1 }">
                              <lightning:button class="btnAddCID" name="{!index}" title="Adicionar outro CID" type="button"
                                                label="ADICIONAR OUTRO CID" onclick="{!c.addCIDrow}"></lightning:button>
                      </aura:if>
                  </div> 
                  <aura:if isTrue="{!index == v.indexValidacao}">
                    <p style="color: red">{!v.msgValidaLookup}</p>
                  </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>
              </lightning:layout>

              <lightning:layout class="slds-m-bottom_x-small">
                <lightning:textarea value="{!v.observacao}" maxlength="255" label="Utilize o espaço para alguma observação, caso necessário (opcional)"
                  variant="standard"></lightning:textarea>
              </lightning:layout>
            </div>
            <div align="right">
              <lightning:button onclick="{!c.cancelarHipotese}" class="btnCancelar" name="Cancelar" title="Cancelar" type="button" label="Cancelar">
              </lightning:button>
              <lightning:button onclick="{!c.salvarHipotese}" class="btnSalvar" name="Salvar" title="Salvar"
                type="button" label="SALVAR">
              </lightning:button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </lightning:card>
    </lightning:layoutItem>

  </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

I'm not putting the helper and the controller because following the error seems to be in the component.

Comment: Hi Diego, you would have to post a minimal code illustrating the problem, otherwise you may not get a proper answer or guidance.

Comment: @Raul The problem is that I do not know where the error is occurring in the .cmp file, so I posted the whole code.

I deploy to QA through a website that is called "JENKINS" and when I'm trying to deploy I get this error.

Comment: If you could compare the code in both the orgs, you might able to narrow down the code snippet that's causing the issue. That's where I would start my issue identification.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your error is in this line:

```html
<aura:attribute name="indexValidacao" type="Integer" default="" />
```

Where you assign an undefined/null/empty value as a default for an integer attribute. Should the value not be specified, I believe you can (and should) remove this `default` attribute. Otherwise, please assign an integer for it, as in `default="0"`.

Comment: I kept the same error @Renato Oliveira :/

Comment: Please update your post with your controller's code. I don't think the error is in your .cmp file.